# Stop tag from being fired if event label is not set

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have 2 tags being fired on one trigger. They collect the values from 2 separate input elements, the only problem is when the submit but is triggered it will collect both values even if one is empty, and it will send the event to google analytic with the label as "not set".

Is it possible to stop one of the tags from being fired if the input is empty for it?

Or can I make it so that "not set" or "null" event labels don't get sent to google analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger, type "custom event" (*), event name ".*" (without quotes) and set "regex" to enabled, firing condition "some events", select your variable name name in the first dropdown, select "does not match regex" as condition and enter ".+" (matches at  least one character).

Then you add this as a trigger exception to the tag.

If there is at least one character in your input field the trigger will evaluate to false and do nothing, if there is no character (i.e. the variable is empty) the condition will evaluate to true and fire an exception.

--

*I suggest a custom event simply so you don't have to worry about picking the correct event, you can just as well use the event that fires your GA tag-